# Anybody know why "x".split(/(x)/).length returns 0 in IE?

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer

In IE, `"x".split(/(x)/).length` returns `0`

In Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera, it returns `3`.

Does anybody know the reason why?  If possible, a reference link will be greatly appreciated.

I believe that it is a IE regex implementation issue, but I can't find any document about that.

Comment: IE6,7,8 as far as I know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct that there are implementation issues.  IE both ignores empty values and capture blocks within regular expressions.

So for

```
"foo".split(/o/)
```

IE gives

```
[f]
```

where the other browsers give

```
["f","",""]
```

and when you add the capturing:

```
"foo".split(/(o)/)
```

IE performs the same, but the others add the captured delimiter to the resulting array to give

```
["f","o","","o",""]
```

So unfortunately you probably either need to avoid using split, or code around these issues.

Answer (score 3):

Here for example http://blog.stchur.com/2007/03/28/split-broken-in-ie/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the broken IE implementation of split.

Here's a small [library](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split) file that fixed the problem perfectly.